# Experience with travelling long hours in a car with a 10-week-old baby?

Tags: newborn, travel

I am due in ten weeks and have planned a trip to Exmouth from Perth over 2 days, 8 hours one day, 4/5 hours the next. Is this feasible with a 10-week-old baby? Has anyone done trips this long with a 10-week-old before?

Comment: Will you be traveling alone with the baby or will there be another adult to help drive?

Comment: Is this Exmouth near Exeter in England and Perth in Scotland (a distance of around 500 miles)?

Comment: Hi folks; a gentle reminder that comments are to clarify the question, not to answer it (not even to leave a 'not long enough for an answer' answer), and not to debate.  Please visit [chat] where we're always happy to discuss!

Answer (score 19):

We did a 9 hour haul from Germany to Denmark with a 6 weeks old and a one year old. No issues or problems. A few things to consider

- Two adults makes this A LOT easier. You can take turns driving, have a conversation and there are always an available pair of hands for the kids.
- Pack properly: water, food, books, toys, books on tape, diaper, change of cloth, ideally all available while driving
- Make sure the car is in good shape. You do NOT want to deal with car troubles in the middle of nowhere with tricky weather conditions. In our case, it was insanely cold, but in your case it may be hot as heck. Both are not good conditions for getting stranded with a few weeks old kid. Make sure you access to car help service, if you need it.
- Consider doing some night driving or whatever your kid's "prime sleep time" is. Sleeping in car seats is actually quite comfortable for the little ones, so you might as well take advantage of it.
- Plan for extra stops, breaks and rest as needed. Edit: DO NOT breast feed in a driving car. It's not safe and potentially illegal; it's much more relaxing if you do it a nice rest stop.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I can upvote with a clean conscience.

Comment: Also make sure the air in the car is not too drafty, dry, hot or cold. We drove 400km with a 3 week old and had to keep the floor of the car wet because otherwise the air in the car would get really dry due to the airco.

Answer (score 9):

As an experienced "road tripper", I believe an 8 hour driving day with a 10 week old will be very challenging, I would split that day into two days.

With a child at that age I would be prepared to stop at least once every 2 hours. You will not be able to schedule all your stops because you can not predict the babies schedule at that age. You might stop at a nice lunch spot for an hour, only to have to pull off the road again 20 minutes after resuming because of a change or spit-up, or simply to rock and burp the little one.  You will need to find a nice safe place to stop and take care of this, and depending on weather you might need to find shade/shelter etc.  The most important thing is to have flexibility in your schedule to accommodate the unexpected.

Also keep in mind that you may be rather under-slept before setting out, simply due to regular baby care at home. My littlest one is around 10 weeks old right now, and although he's a wonderful sleeper overall we still end up with rough nights here and there.

For myself, travelling with our little ones, we plan for 30 to 45 minutes of stoppage time for every 2 hours of drive time. And this is ignoring the needs of any adults or older children on the trip.  Additionally, if driving more than 4 hours we plan a long break around the 4 hour mark at a chosen location. A rest stop, park or the like where everyone can get out and relax, eat, get refreshed etc. This usually adds about an hour, not including any extra time needed to drive to/from the resting location.

For the older occupants, the stoppages take a toll, they increase fatigue and and the need for more stops for bathroom breaks and meals etc.  Remember that you might find yourself taking care of the littlest one in spots that offer no services for the rest of the group.

All in all, we expect 4 hours of actual driving time to take as much as 6 or 7 hours. This represents a realistic worst case scenario. It's better to plan for the worst case and end up ahead of schedule, rather than end up behind schedule and having to rush to make up time.

Taking all that into account, I would stretch your drive over 3 days rather than 2. Plan for 4 or 5 hours of actual driving time each day, with plenty of stops expected. Make note of several possible overnight/sleep locations in advance for each night, so you can decide where to stop for the night based on each days progress. If your little one sleeps like an angel and needs only one change, you'll make great time and get in early. If they cry non stop and need constant attention, you'll still end up arriving roughly on schedule.

Comment: Why you think the OP would need to stop every 2 hours or more (do all 10 week old babies wake up every 2 hours?) I don't have a 10 week old, but I did a lot of traveling with babies (from the NE to Florida by car or, more mercifully, by plane) and don't remember stopping the car every two hours. Rest stops are for kids and adults, as needed. Ten week old babies don't need them.

Comment: Primarily - nursing, burping, changes and spit-up events, with a secondary risk of just general discomfort/crying.  Personally I would never allow someone to nurse in my moving vehicle.  A 10 month may still be nursing every 2 hours, soiling a couple diapers in an 8 hour period, and easily spit up or need burping after each feed also, all at different times. It's not every 2 hours on the dot, it's oh they slept for four hours, and over the next 3 hours we had to stop 5 times.   I've experienced 4+ stops on a 2 hour drive more than once. Note that I addressed adult rest stops separately.

Comment: I think you've overestimated the need to stop; that's your experience. It's far from mine, and likely not average.

Comment: So there are basically 2 reasonable spots to stop between Exmouth and Perth:
Carnarvon and Geraldton. And stopping at both would divide the journey into *roughly* equal 3rds. However, outside of those options are fairly limited unless you have a van (or are willing to set up a tent).  They do exist (at least I think), but are fairly sparse, particularly at the northern end.

Comment: @anongoodnurse certainly I am overestimating the need to stop. The thrust of my answer is to plan for the worst and hope for the best, perhaps that isn't clear. Most trips will go a lot smoother, but it's much more pleasant to get places ahead of schedule rather than be pushed into an unexpected 14hr day on the road

Comment: @anongoodnurse, assuming this is Perth and Exmouth in Western Australia it is advised (major advertising campaigns leading up to long weekends) for drivers to stop and stretch *at least every two hours*. Long flat, straight roads and driver fatigue can lead to microsleeping which is definitely not a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this feasable with a 10 week old baby?

It depends on a lot of factors, but this is doable with a 10 week old baby. At 10 weeks, babies don't have much of a schedule, so whatever they do, they can pretty much do in a car. What *you* will be able to do is another matter.

You need to factor in that you will be tired and sleep deprived. Also, you can't count on eight hours of uninterrupted driving. If you are traveling alone, you'll need to stop to feed, change and burp the baby at least once, most likely twice, possibly more. It will be much easier for you if you have an adult companion to let you sleep when the baby sleeps.

Plan for and around these obstacles and it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you the one driving? Especially at that age you can't expect your kid to fit any kind of schedule. If you're lucky he/she will sleep most of the time. However what are you going to do if your kid is awake (or even crying)?

I've taken 4 hour trips with kids that i think were 4 months old. And the hard part is that it can easily add an hour to your schedule. Just diaper changes, feeding, playing. And that was while my wife was with  me. Don't expect to be able to say 'just another half hour, then we'll stop again. Reasoning is not something that works at that age. You'll have to fit your trip around their needs.

If you are trying to do this alone i would strongly recommend against it because a kid is so much of a distraction that you can't drive that long safely, even if your kid if fully cooperating.

Answer (score 1):

I had to drive 1600 km with a less than 2 weeks old baby. We actually done this in 4 days (2 adults, kids of 4, 2 and 0 years of age). I don't remember any problems - if all kids were sleeping, we drove on, if they needed tending, we stopped. My wife sat backseat with the newborn to watch over him. I think the longest continuous stretch was around 3 hours, but usually we had to stop every 90-120 minutes. Breaks usually took around an hour, mostly for the 2 and 4 years old to move. Actually with the newborn it is simple, in my experience they get to sleep about 5 minutes after starting (once I even got him into the car to drive around a block when we couldn't get him to sleep). I believe 8 hours driving in a day is not feasible, make the trip 3 days.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should reconsider this. Does it really have to be done over just 2 days? Can you not stretch it to 4 days?

Having a 10wo baby in a car seat for that length of time is very unfair, potentially unsafe, and just should not be done unless absolutely unavoidable. Even if the SIDS link is unproven, do you really want to test the theory?

Consider how you might feel being strapped into a car seat with no visibility, and no idea what's going on for that length of time. I can't imagine you'd be enjoying it much either.

Comment: I don't know what you imagine goes through a 10 week old's mind while riding in a car... or anywhere else. Can you provide good reasons for your opinion? (Why is it "unfair"? Why is it potentially unsafe?)

Comment: Babies are just small little people. If a situation would be uncomfortable or stressful for an adult, it will also be stressful for a baby.

Comment: Your opinion ("Babies are just small little people. If a situation would be uncomfortable or stressful for an adult, it will also be stressful for a baby.") is not proof, nor is it a good explanation. Please provide a source to support your answer, or this answer may be deleted.

Comment: Others have said that it's fine, without providing any evidence or studies to backup their opinion. Why the inconsistency? My opinion is based on my experience of raising 2 children and observing that long car rides made them very stressed.

Comment: We're talking about a 10 week baby, not kids in general. Your post attracted a post notice for stating as a fact that whatever stresses adults stresses infants. There are thousands if not millions of adult-stressful things that don't affect infants. If infants consistently cried on car rides, you'd have something to support your statement. The fact is, they don't.

Comment: @user1751825 If you have specific experience with this kind of trip and this age  of child, please edit the answer to include that - we value experience as well as direct evidence.  I'd caution you to not assume a 2 or 3 year old will be the same as a 10 week old, though; for one thing, 10 week olds don't get bored nearly as quickly.

Comment: As far as the reason you've got a post notice and others don't; you're suggesting a fact at least indirectly (that SIDS is a concern).  The appearance of precision in your post without the actual evidence to back it up is the problem.  Someone posting their opinion about something non-factual will just not get very many votes; but if someone posts something as a fact, it needs evidence.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1751825 A good example reason why you need to think about references, is my experience with raising 3 kids is that they loved travel from a very early age. As babies, they slept peacefully on long journeys.